# Regular Expression (Regex) not working for all samples of geographical coordinates (decimal format)

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have created a regular expression to extract geographical coordinates (decimal format) data from a specific pattern of strings.
Regex: `/(?<lat>\-?\d+\.\d+)(?<comma>\,)(?<long>\-?\d+\.\d+)/gm`

sample of strings that are working: `11.18531,88.78292`,`8.34329,123.48655`, `21.11912,145.85430`, `36.29781,-13.06121`, `-16.35564,-36.07065`, `31.86691,122.28366`, `38.84814,-140.10204`, `18.58158,59.20813`

Here I want to extract the latitude and longitude values with their `-` signs.

But there are some patterns of string which I want to reject completely: `-76.84933,-141.64907hel`, `no-16.3993,-11.2359`, `-77.7678er,161.9786`, `69.8149,-l61.9041`, `5.9333,10.1rr667`, `jkl11.18531,88.78292hh`

But few of the above strings are passing the [`regex.test()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp) as `true`: `-76.84933,-141.64907hel`, `no-16.3993,-11.2359`, `5.9333,10.1rr667`, `jkl11.18531,88.78292hh`. For these types of strings, I want to return `false`. No match should be found for these strings like these. These are very much contaminated and don't want to work on them further.

Visit https://regex101.com/r/rT6YvD/1 to see the regex playground I am using.

This is what I am not able to achieve. Please help!!!

Any suggestion accepted gratefully. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/AIQXOy/1 ?

Comment: @Jan I provided that so that the person trying to answer the question, can see what I was doing.

Comment: Did you actually look at @Jan's link?  S/he fixed your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<lat>-?\b(?<!\b-)\d+\.\d+)(?<comma>,)(?<long>-?\d+\.\d+)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RFu9LP/1). *Details*:

- `(?<lat>-?\b(?<!\b-)\d+\.\d+)` - Group "lat": an optional `-`, a word boundary that is not immediately preceded with a `-` that has a word char in front of it, and then one or more digits, `.` and one or more digits
- `(?<comma>,)` - Group "comma": a comma
- `(?<long>-?\d+\.\d+)` - Group "long": an optional `-`, one or more digits, `.` and one or more digits
- `\b` - a word boundary

If you need to make sure the string only contains the cooordinates, you can remove all whitespaces and then check if the whole string matches your coordinates pattern:

```js
const match = text
    .replace(/\s+/g, '')
    .match(/^(?<lat>-?\d+\.\d+)(?<comma>,)(?<long>-?\d+\.\d+)$/);
```

Here, `^` matches the start of string, and `$` matches the end of string.